# Apply the Herfindahl-Hirschman Index function to a group of rows for an individual in R

Tags: r, function

I have a dataframe with multiple rows per individual. Each individual has an ID. Also each row per person has a column with a percentage that add up to 100 across the rows.

Dataframe DF below:

| ID | Percentage |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 |
| 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 25 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 2 | 45 |
| 2 | 10 |

I want to apply the Herfindahl-Hirschman Index (hhi function) to compute the index by person. The function is hhi(x, s) and has two arguments. x = the object, s = the value column (percentage in this case). So far, I've tried the following but it doesn't work. It still computes the index across the entire dataframe.

setDT(df)[,hhi(df, "percentage"), ID]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary: You spelled Percentage incorrectly, although that appears to be from a failure to copy your code precisely. The real problem as you pointed out is that the data.table function is using the entire column of Percentage values each time through the `by`-loop. The correct way to refer to a `by`-constructed subset of data is with the .SD (**S**ubset-of-**D**ata) construct.

Here's the MCVE

```
library(hhi)
 
 df <- read.table(text="ID  Percentage
 1  50
 1  50
 2  25
 2  20
 2  45
 2  10", head=T)

library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df[,hhi(df, "percentage"), ID]
#------------------
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, i, j) : undefined columns selected
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, i, j) : undefined columns selected
In addition: Warning message:
In hhi(df, "percentage") : shares, "s", do not sum to 100
#-----------------
df[,hhi(df, "Percentage"), ID]  # correct spelling
   ID   V1
1:  1 8150
2:  2 8150
Warning messages:
1: In hhi(df, "Percentage") : shares, "s", do not sum to 100
2: In hhi(df, "Percentage") : shares, "s", do not sum to 100
```

That is apparently what you are seeing and it is because you have not correctly told the `[.data.table` function that the `df` is that same `df` as is being evaluated by subset. To do that correctly you need to use the `.SD` self-(subset)referential operation.

```
df[,hhi(.SD, "Percentage"), by=ID]

#-----------
   ID   V1
1:  1 5000
2:  2 3150    # no warnings, more sensible indices of concentration
```

It's interesting to compare a base version of this operation to the data.table and another poster's dplyr version. I happen to think that as far as elegance goes, the winner is base-R although there definitely is a motivation for learning the somewhat idiosyncratic, and sometimes elegant, syntax of the `[.data.table` function for it's speed and efficiency (lower memory footprint) for large datasets.

```
lapply( split(df, df$ID), hhi, s="Percentage")
$`1`
[1] 5000

$`2`
[1] 3150
```

Comment: Thank you so much for tackling this issue! That is an elegant solution. After some tinkering, I also found this to work. However, it isn't as compact. 

h<-do.call("rbind", as.list(
  by(df, list(group = df$ID), function(x){
    y <-subset(x, select = -ID)
    hhi(y, "Percentage")})))

Comment: You could get the same result by changing my ‘lapply” to “sapply”.

Answer (score 0):

IRTFM's solution is excellent and elegant. Here is a dply solution as well. There is probably a simpler way to do this with an anonymous function or dplyr group_by

```r
library(dplyr)
library(hhi)
library(purrr)

compute_hhi<-function(df){
  hhi=hhi( df %>% as.data.frame(.),"Percentage")
  id=df %>% pluck("ID") %>% head(1)
  data.frame(id,hhi)
}

df_hhi<-df %>%
  group_split(ID, .keep=TRUE) %>%
  map(compute_hhi) %>%
  bind_rows()

df_hhi
#>   id  hhi
#> 1  1 5000
#> 2  2 3150
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>